# FW1FontWrapper IFW1ColorRGBA

Tags: c++, directx-11

I've been trying to convert an RGBA color to a UINT32 to use in IFW1FontWrapper->DrawString function, but it's crashing the game.

```
IFW1ColorRGBA *color;
color->SetColor(r, g, b, a);//Crash
UINT32 clr = color->GetColor32();
color->Release();
```

r, g, b, a type is FLOAT
Anyone can help me getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cody Gray your code did not work, but you helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

This is the final code that works:

```
IFW1ColorRGBA* pColor;
UINT32 clr = 0xffffffff;
pfw1Factory->CreateColor(clr, &pColor);
pColor->SetColor(r, g, b, a);
clr = pColor->GetColor32();
```

Comment: Well, of course the code didn't work. I wasn't intended to be copied and pasted. Your question only told us that you were using DirectX 11, but there is no DirectX interface by the name IFW1ColorRGBA or FW1FontWrapper. This must be some class library that you've gotten somewhere, or something you've written yourself. How do you expect us to know that when you don't tell us? So I had no idea what function you're supposed to call with that class library to create a color. Generally, in DirectX, you would use QueryInterface. Apparently this one's different. Good to see you've puzzled it out.

Comment: You should probably still check to make sure that CreateColor has succeeded. If it's a standard COM-based interface, it will return an HRESULT, which you check for success using the SUCCEEDED macro. Otherwise, dereferencing pColor will still lead to a crash in the event that the function fails to create the color.

Comment: Ok I will do that, & I'm using the FW1FontWrapper library for the drawing

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> IFW1ColorRGBA *color;
> ```

This line declares a pointer-to-`IFW1ColorRGBA`. It does not, however, *initialize* that pointer. It certainly does not *allocate any memory* to store an object. Therefore, what you have here is an uninitialized pointer.

> ```
> color->SetColor(r, g, b, a);//Crash
> ```

Then you go and try to *dereference* that uninitialized pointer. The `->` operator dereferences the pointer and calls the `SetColor` member function. **BOOM!** You've invoked undefined behavior and you crash. That pointer didn't actually point to a valid `IFW1ColorRGBA` object. Oops.

You need to initialize that pointer. Since it's actually an interface type, you would probably do so by calling the `QueryInterface` function on some drawing object (we'll call it `pDrawingSomethingOrOther`).
For example:

```
IFW1ColorRGBA* pColor;
HRESULT hResult = pDrawingSomethingOrOther->QueryInterface(&pColor);
if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
{
    pColor->SetColor(r, g, b, a);
    UINT32 clr = pColor->GetColor32();
    pColor->Release();
}
```